# Регулярные выражения, проверить, но не запомнить

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
var task;
task = '(X^2+X^2)+X^2';
task = task.replace(/(^|\+)X\^2\b/g, '+1X^2');
```

на выходе task будет равен `(X^2+1X^2)+1X^2`.
Как сделать так, чтоб на выходе task был равен `(+1X^2+1X^2)+1X^2`?
Мне нужно просто сделать так, чтоб он считывал скобку, но не запоминал ее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var task;
task = '(X^2+X^2)+X^2';
task = task.replace(/(?:^|\+)?X\^2\b/g, '+1X^2');
```

`(?:)` - незапоминающиеся скобки

У вас в первом случае нет ни степени, ни плюса, по-этому оно его и не учитывает. Нужно после скобки добавить знак `?`, что бы регулярно выражение принимало, даже если этих символов нет

Comment: Мне нужно не запоминать только '(', все остальное должно запомниться.

Comment: @Alex3214, не понял.

Comment: Ну, в общем, только что попробовал, но все еще не помогает( Есть еще способы?

Comment: @Alex3214, может так? `(?:^|\+)?X\^2\b`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Можете объяснить, что происходит там, зачем нужен еще один знак вопроса?

Comment: @Alex3214, знак вопроса показывает, что эти символы могут там и не быть. Если вы укажите просто `/12/`, то регулярное выражение будет принимать только `12`. А если вы укажите `/1?2/`, то будет принимать `12` и просто `2`